# Is there a standard ISO language code for ”other”?

Tags: standards

I’m making a website, and using ISO standard two letter language codes for tagging user-submitted content. I’m not intending on adding every single language, but would like an *other* category. It’s not a huge problem, but it got me wondering, is there a standard code for *other*? If there is nothing official, is there a common convention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two-letter codes are defined in [ISO 639-1](https://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/iso639-1.html) and the current list does not contain a code for "other". (As [Wikipedia's list of ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) shows, not all possible two-letter codes have been used so far, i.e. only 184 out 676 possible codes, so it is *theoretically* possible that such a code gets added later.)

Since the possible number of codes allowed by two-letter codes is much too low for the world's languages, ISO has defined three-letter codes in ISO 639-3. However, I am not aware of an ISO 639-3 code for "other" language. The standard has a few [special codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3#Special_codes) for situations when you can't use a language code:

- `mis`: for documents using uncoded languages, i.e. languages don't have a ISO code (yet);
- `mul`: for documents using multiple languages (however, in markup languages, you can use the `lang` attribute on specific elements that contain content in a single language);
- `und`: for documents where the language has not been identified;
- `zxx`: for documents without any linguistic content.

The closest match with what you need is **`und`**.

Comment: Correct.  Here is a good example of using `und`: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2015/evaluating-language-identification-performance.html

Answer (score 3):

In Addition to @Tsundoku's answer, there is a kind of private use area in ISO 639-3: In addition, 520 codes in the range `qaa`–`qtz` are 'reserved for local use'. So you can assign in your application the code `qot` for "other" when you want to do this. Note that the same code can have completely different assignments on other places.

Addition in reply to the comments: There is no such option with ISO 693-1 **two** letter codes, all codes in there are assigned to languages.

Comment: OP specifies that they are using two-letter language codes, i.e. ISO 639-1, not ISO 639-3. From a quick look it doesn't seem that these codes have ISO 639-1 equivalents, or that there is any private use area in ISO 639-1 (although there are many unassigned code points), but this answer would be substantially improved by discussing ISO 639-1 explicitly, even if only to explain why it does not offer a good solution, and ISO 639-3 should be used instead

Comment: the OP says "using ISO standard two letter language codes". The ISO standard two letter codes are ISO 639-1

Comment: Ok, I see it now

Comment: no worries. The answer already addressed the underlying concern in the question, I just wanted to make sure the two letter case was explicitly addressed for anyone coming across it later